# can seem to export environment variable from bash script

Tags: bash, environment-variables, variable-assignment

I am working on a remote server through putty and am trying to set certain environment variables throught something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR="SOME VALUE"
export $VAR
```

when I exit the script and run echo on $VAR, I am given a blank line. could you please suggest a way around this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need to export VAR, rather than $VAR.

Plus, I think, you are trying to execute the script from your shell as

```
./initVars.sh # or whatever is your script name...
```

You should rather source it as

```
source ./initVars.sh # OR
. ./initVars.sh # Note the leading '.' which serves as short-hand for source.
```

You can put it in your .bashrc.

Comment: can u tell me how to do the same in windows batch file

Comment: For batch file, *i think* that you can simply call the .bat file from parent file, as "initVars.bat". Make sure that it does not have any exit statement. Plus, to set a var, you need to use the command "set", like `set VAR="SOME VALUE"`

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
export VAR
```

Note the lack of the dollar sign symbol.

Comment: Are you running bash? Try this: `echo $0` from the command prompt. If you don't see `bash` or `sh`, then it won't work.

Comment: @HaiVu It won't work for the reason in anishane's answer. `export` is POSIX, so it should work in sh as well.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems. First, it's just `export VAR`. Second, `$VAR` will only be available to your script and child processes, not to the parent shell. You can source it like `. ./yourscript.sh` from the shell if you want `$VAR` to be set for that shell.